# Error : Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've tried to create Main class in my package ("testing").
It was created in same package where i've created my object class. (i.e. Car)

but when running the Main class (Test3), i'm getting the following error.
pls see screen shot.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zW1e.png)

Comment: Is your `Test3.java` file in a `testing` directory? Did you try to run the main class from the CLI?

Comment: If you dont have much code in the project, try to set up a new one. Often more easy then fixen the error.

Answer (score 0):

When it happens to me I'm checking two things, try one or both:

1. go to `.classpath` file and open it with notepad check verify that all paths are exist.
2. right click on your project--> "Build path"-->"Configure build path" -->"Orders and Export", try to uncheck "JRE System Library".

Let me know if it works for you.